# UITabBar ignoring occasional "clicks"

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uitabbar

I'm working on an iPhone app that has a UITabBar. Occasionally the tab bar ignores my "clicks" (or "taps", or whatever they're called in the iPhone world). It happens on both the simulator and the on the device. Clicking on a tab bar button won't result in any action, and I have to click it several times for the expected action to occur.

Can anybody shed any light on what might be causing this issue, or how I can go about debugging it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read somewhere that the UITabBar becomes unresponsive when it is not the immediate child of the window. It can be something like that or you might have a UIScrollView or some other view interfering with your UITabBar.

P.S 
Click is correct for buttons, including tabs. For others, a widely used term is touch.

Comment: I've reshuffled my views so that the tab bar is the immediate child of the window, and it all works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This might be happening bcoz the view is not getting loaded when you click on the tab. 
Are you using any url request in the -(void)viewDidLoad method. If this is the case may be ur internet is workin slowly.

Comment: I don't think that is the issue, because the tab bar isn't event receiving the click events.